# One WiFi network not working, others are fine

Tags: networking, wireless, thinkpad

There is one particular network that when I connect to it, everything is usually fine for a few minutes but then the WiFi symbol in the top right will turn into a question mark and the connection gets very bad.
It says I'm still connected to the network and a YouTube video will continue to play but if I try to open a new web page it wont load.
The strength of the connection is good and this same network works fine on my phone all the time.

- Thinkpad T460p
- Ubuntu 19.04
- Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)

I've tried disabling IPv6 on the network as suggested somewhere but that didn't work.

No idea how to debug this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] and define "not working". Is it not visible when scanning or it is but can't connect or it can but seems to not have internet access?

Comment: *if I try to open a new web page it wont load*: why? Name not resolved? Nothing downloads? Any proxy set up on that network? Is there a correlation with Wifi type (802.11 a/b/g/n)?

Comment: Can you go [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), then [edit] your question and provide full details when connected to a network that does work and the one that doesn't?  Then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: It seems like Docker was causing a problem? I've uninstalled it and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This docker support forum has various answers to check out:

- [Wifi Adapter Disabled When Hyper-V Network Adapter Enabled - Native](https://forums.docker.com/t/wifi-adapter-disabled-when-hyper-v-network-adapter-enabled-native/18063/8)

The easiest answer (not guaranteed to work for you) says:

> I changed the subnet address on docker settings to match my wifi ipv4
>   address and it worked for me.

[image: docker.png]

Even if this doesn't solve the problem you should read the whole thread and search the rest of the docker forum for similar questions.